# Memory leaks when using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm developing an iPhone app using SDK 4.1 targeting iOS 4.1 or newer.
Instruments report memory leaks for the code below.

```
void (^resultBlock)(ALAsset *) = ^(ALAsset *asset) {
    NSLog(@"resultBlock");
};
void (^failureBlock)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
};
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000176&ext=JPG"];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
[library release];
```

I just put this code in viewDidLoad of my TestApp for test.(I'm using with UIImagePicker in my actual project.)
When I run the TestApp using Instrument(leak), it report memory leaks about 10 seconds after launch.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this code or is there something else that I should do?
Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I am trying to track it down myself.

Have you found a resolution?

Comment: That "10 seconds after launch" timing happens, because by default Instruments takes a snapshot every 10 seconds. You can change this time in Leaks - Snapshots - Snapshot Interval (sec). You can also take a manual snapshot at any time in same location.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong with your memory management in the code you’ve provided. If there is a leak, it’s in Apple’s frameworks or another part of your code. Just make sure you’re testing on the device—some frameworks have much more “polish” on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've not found any resolution yet. But it seems that the memory leak happens only once and does not give any bad influences except the leaks, so I just ignored this problem. 
Apple did not reject my app for this problem.